# Reading recommendation on using statistical analysis in online fraud prevention

Tags: references, fraud-detection

Can you please recommend good reads on statistical analysis related to online fraud detection and prevention of account abuse?

Thank you.

Comment: I think in order to get some answers you'll need to give more details about what sort of fraud or abuse and what sort of detection.